# Check whether one of the attributes contains given value or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery, xquery-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have the following code

```
    DECLARE @p varchar(4)
    SET @p = ext1

    DECLARE @x xml
    SET @x = '<labels defaultText = "Some text 2012">      
                <label text = "Some text1" />      
                <label text = "Some text2" />      
                <label text = "Some text3" />
              </labels>'
```

Please, help to write an xpath/xquery query to check whether defaultText value or one of the texts' values contain @p or not. In this example the result will be true , because value of the text in the first label contains ext1.

Comment: can you also add the sql query which you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.nodes()` to iterate through `<label>` and use `.value()` for value of root node attribute as well as for values of attribute of `<label>`. Something like this

```
DECLARE @p varchar(4)
SET @p = 'ext1'

DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = '<labels defaultText = "Some text 2012">      
    <label text = "Some text1" />      
    <label text = "Some text2" />      
    <label text = "Some text3" />
    </labels>'

DECLARE @check BIT = 0

SELECT TOP 1 @check  =  1
FROM @x.nodes('labels/label') as t(c)
WHERE  c.value('@text','VARCHAR(20)') LIKE '%' + @p +'%'
    OR @x.value('/labels[1]/@defaultText','VARCHAR(20)') LIKE  '%' + @p +'%'

SELECT @check
```